# How can I contact Firefox support without my login credentials? My login is not working and their Twitter account has not been useful

Tags: firefox, security, login, firefox-profile, recovery

I was forced to refresh Windows 10, upon trying to login Firefox I found out that I have the password but I don't have the security or recovery code. Both of my email addresses are configured in Firefox but it's not letting me login without security or recovery code, how can I get back the access?

I am unable to contact FF as their support portal also ask for login with security or recovery code and their twitter account has not been helpful.

Even if my account cannot be recovered, there should be a way to delete it so that I can create a new one with my email address.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't act carefully enough and won't be able to do what you want. As per Firefox Help articles:

[What if I'm locked out of Two-Step Authentication?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-if-im-locked-out-two-step-authentication)

> I lost my two-step authentication device, can’t find recovery codes and don’t have a logged-in device.
>
> Unfortunately, deactivation of two-step authentication is not supported and you will not be able access your existing Sync data. You can however create a new account with a different email address to begin syncing again.

[How do I delete my Firefox Account?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-delete-my-firefox-account) tells you, you need to login to delete the account, which you can not do. As such you won't be able to delete the account. You might try to reach their support using a different account with a different E-Mail. Personally I'd assume the chance you will get help that way is rather low.

Comment: I even have emails firefox sent me when I activated TFA but they don't contain any codes.

Comment: Depending on when you created that account it might not have been a feature. Seems like it was [introduced in September 2018](https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/firefox-accounts-offer-recovery-key-option/). You could try to look for `<your_email> Firefox Recovery Codes.txt. ` as outlined by the help. If you don't have any other device that's currently logged it (which seems odd, why use sync if you only use it on a single device?) you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I have the emails where it says the TFA has been activated but none of those emails contain any code, thus it looks like FF showed the codes on the screen only. I used to hav FF on mob but not anymore, I used sync so that after reinstallation of FF, I could get all bookmarks, settings, passwords etc back. I am ready to leave all that but atleast FF should return my email address.